# Run midori with python , grab text from webpage

Tags: python

I'm doing a small project trying to open Midori on my RaspPi, grab text from an API webpage and use it as a variable in a python code. The same page will reload after maybe 10sec and the python code will grab the new variable and loop forever

I'm reading the midori terminal commands help page but not really understanding even how to use the commands in terminal.

I realise that urllib and requests are better libraries but due to specific reasons I'd prefer to open midori. Currently, this is what I have :

```
import subprocess as sub
pageToOpen="http://sgnextbus.honcheng.com/ltamytransport/getarrivaltime?svc=291&busstop=76439"
sub.Popen(["midori", "-a", pageToOpen])
```

Comment: This case opens just a web browser window, without storing any response; isn't there any possibility to use e.g. subprocess with curl, which can return your response as a string to python code?

Comment: ya , I'm hoping someone in this forum can help with that question too.